# I have an 'error' with my code

Tags: rfid

The following code gives me an error:

```
// RFIDunio.h is from http://learn.robotgeek.com/getting-started-guides/39-robot-kits/151-rfiduino.html
#include <RFIDuino.h> 

byte    keyTag[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
boolean noise = false;
byte    masterTag[5] = {37,0,0,127,24};
byte    tagData[5];
byte    tagDatas[5];
boolean verifyKey = false;
boolean mastaKey = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Welcome to my system!");
}

RFIDuino myRFIDuino(1.2);

void loop()
{
  if(myRFIDunio.scanForTag(tagData == true)
  {
    verifyKey = myRFIDunio.compareTagData(tagData, keyTag);
    mastaKey = myRFIDunio.compareTagData(tagData, masterTag);
    if(verifyKey == true)
    {
      digitalWrite(myRFIDunio.led2,HIGH);
      if(noise == true)
      {
        myRFIDunio.successSound();
      }
      Serial.println("Correct Key!" + " UID = " + tagData[5]);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(myRFIDunio.led2,LOW);
    }
    else if(mastaKey == true)
    {
      Serial.println("Programming mode activated!");
      delay(500);
      Serial.println("Please scan a card.");
      myRFIDunio.scanForTag(tagDatas == true)
      delay(1000);
      tagDatas[5] = tagData[5];
      Serial.println("Card has been programmed!");
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(myRFIDuno.led1,HIGH);
      if(noise == true)
         {
            myRFIDuino.errorSound();        
         }
      Serial.println("Wrong! " + "UID = " + tagData[5]);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(myRFIDunio.led1,LOW);
    }
  }
```

The error is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=106 -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\variants\standard -IC:\Users\*****\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RFIDuino C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\build6101268048586666869.tmp\sketch_jul24a.cpp -o C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\build6101268048586666869.tmp\sketch_jul24a.cpp.o 
sketch_jul24a.ino: In function 'void loop()':
sketch_jul24a:20: error: 'myRFIDunio' was not declared in this scope
sketch_jul24a:20: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
sketch_jul24a:21: error: expected `)' before '{' token
sketch_jul24a:55: error: expected statement at end of input
sketch_jul24a:55: error: expected `}' at end of input
```

Comment: Did you even read the errors?! It tells you precisely what's wrong. `error: 'myRFIDunio' was not declared` - because you've spelt it incorrectly. In fact, you've managed to spell it three different ways throughout your code: `myRFIDuino`; `myRFIDunio`; `myRFIDuno`. Read, read, and read again.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is spelling-sensitive; identifiers need to be spelled the same way each time they are used.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myRFIDunio.scanForTag(tagData == true)
```

I think you have a bracket missing there.

```
if(myRFIDunio.scanForTag(tagData) == true)
```

Also I think you have spelled myRFIDuino wrong.  ni <-> in

```
if(myRFIDuino.scanForTag(tagData) == true)
```

And you need a } at the end of your program.

As well, you can't add strings together like you are doing in your Serial prints.  Break them up into multiple prints:

```
Serial.print("Correct Key!  UID = ");
Serial.println(tagData[5]);
```

You also have other bits that make no sense at all, such as:

```
myRFIDuino.scanForTag(tagDatas == true)
```

One further thing - that library will never work on Linux, or on MAC OS/X where case sensitivity is enabled on the filesystem.  The .cpp file is including a badly named .h file.

Comment: myRFIDunio.scanForTag(tagDatas == true)    is for getting the card information so you can program it, I am on windows. I will change the serial prints.                                                                                                         http://pastebin.com/RMrE8aD0

Comment: That line is gibberish, unless you are wanting to pass a boolean value to the scanForTag function which states whether or not tagDatas is true, which it can't be since it's an array.  Why is the `== true` even there?!

Comment: I am just trying to figure this out. Is there any way to get the tag data then.  and put it into a byte.

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know what "the tag data is", only that your program has syntax errors that I have identified.  I do not know what the program is supposed to do - nor even what a "RFIDuino" is or what it does.

Comment: Tag data is what rfid tags hold, they all have indiffrent unique ids. This reads them. I can show you the library if you want.

Comment: I have seen the library.  I have even submitted a pull request to it to correct their capitalization error.  I have never seen an RFID tag that just has a single byte for it's ID though.  If you want help with working out how to use the library then look at the examples.  First correct the syntax errors like I have told you.

Comment: @IanOxyMoron: If you have further questions then you would be best served by opening further questions.